# Tooltip on Rallygrid

Tags: tooltip, rally

I am looking for an example of implementing a custom tooltip to a rallygrid.  I have attempted to use the renderer config on a column, but not luck so far.  Does anyone have a working example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: To insure correct timing and deletion of tooltip I called `showNow()` method on tooltip and used its `destroyAfterHide` config property

```
    listeners: {
        itemmouseenter: function(g, record, item, index, e, eOpts) {
            console.log(record.get('FormattedID'));
            Ext.create('Rally.ui.tooltip.ToolTip', {
                target : item,
                destroyAfterHide: true,
                hideDelay: 0,
                html: '<p><strong>This is a tooltip: ' + record.get('FormattedID') + '</strong></p>'
            }).showNow();
```

Here is the full example example of using [Rally.ui.tooltip.Tooltip](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.tooltip.ToolTip) with rallygrid:

[image]

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
extend: 'Rally.app.App',
componentCls: 'app',
launch: function() {
    Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Store', {
        model: 'userstory',
        autoLoad: true,
        listeners: {
            load: this._onDataLoaded,
            scope: this
        },
        fetch: ['FormattedID', 'Name', 'ScheduleState', 'Tasks', 'Defects']
    });
},
_onDataLoaded: function(store, data) {
    var records = _.map(data, function(record) {
        return Ext.apply({
            TaskCount: record.get('Tasks').Count
        }, record.getData());
    });

    this.add({
        xtype: 'rallygrid',
        showPagingToolbar: false,
        editable: true,
        store: Ext.create('Rally.data.custom.Store', {
            data: records
        }),
        listeners: {
            itemmouseenter: function(g, record, item, index, e, eOpts) {
                console.log(record.get('FormattedID'));
                Ext.create('Rally.ui.tooltip.ToolTip', {
                    target : item,
                    destroyAfterHide: true,
                    hideDelay: 0,
                    html: '<p><strong>This is a tooltip: ' + record.get('FormattedID') + '</strong></p>'
                }).showNow();
            },
            select: this.getRecordOnSelectedRow,
            load : function(g, record, index, options){
                this.getRecordOnSelectedRow(g, record, 0, options);
            },
            scope: this
        },
        columnCfgs: [
            {
                xtype: 'templatecolumn',
                text: 'ID',
                dataIndex: 'FormattedID',
                width: 100,
                tpl: Ext.create('Rally.ui.renderer.template.FormattedIDTemplate')
            },
            {
                text: 'Name',
                dataIndex: 'Name'
            },
            {
                text: 'Schedule State',
                dataIndex: 'ScheduleState',
            },
            {
                text: '# of Tasks',
                dataIndex: 'TaskCount',
            },
            {
                text: '# of Defects',
                dataIndex: 'Defects',
                renderer: function(value) {
                    return value.Count;
                }
            }
        ]
    });
},
getRecordOnSelectedRow:function(g, record, rowIndex, options){
    console.log(record);
}
```

});

Comment: this is a great start, thanks for the example.  The only issue is that the tooltip is built after the mouse enter, and does not appear until exiting and reentering.  Is there a way to build this so that it is ready for the first mouse enter?

Comment: any ideas on building the tooltip previous to itemmouseenter? @nickm

Comment: @SeanHogan I updated the code above. itemmouseenter is the correct event, but the timing can be more precise by using showNow() method